# Error on upload to FTP server using Python

Tags: python, upload, ftp, connection

I am using Python to upload a file to FTP server. My code is below

```
import ftplib
s = ftplib.FTP('123.123.123.123', 'username', 'password')
f = open('filename to upload', 'rb')
s.storbinary('STOR filename', f)
```

This code gives me an error.

```
soccet.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

When I use C#.net to do this task, there is no problem at all. My C# code is below:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(FtpURL + filename);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.UseBinary = true;
request.UsePassive = false;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(FullFilePath);
byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
fs.Close();

Stream ftpstream = request.GetRequestStream();
ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
ftpstream.Close();
```

Comment: are you sure that the remote machine running standart ftp server on 21 port, and the port isn't firewalled?

Comment: first try a third party software, and then use your own.Filezilla etc.

Comment: I tried to connect remote machine using Totalcommander. It was ok.

Comment: On my remote machine, I added 21 port in Inbound rules of the firewall.

Comment: in you c# you are not using passive mode, whereas in python the default is passive mode on.